# TFS 2010 + MSDeploy when solution has multiple web applications

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild, msdeploy

I have two solutions

- SolutionA.sln

  - WebApplication1.csproj
- SolutionB.sln

  - WebApplication1.csproj
  - WebApplication2.csproj

I also have two TFS 2010 build configurations

- BuildConfigA

  - should build SolutionA and deploy WebApplication1
- BuildConfigB

  - should build SolutionB and deploy WebApplication2 (but not
    WebApplication1)

To prevent BuildConfigB from trying to deploy WebApplication1, I put a `<DeployOnBuild>false</DeployOnBuild>` in WebApplication1.csproj. But that also prevents BuildConfigA from deploying it. How could I accomodate this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up deciding to do. I now have three solutions

- SolutionA.sln

  - WebApplication1.csproj
- SolutionB.sln

  - WebApplication1.csproj
  - WebApplication2.csproj
- SolutionC.sln

  - WebApplication2.csproj

I do most of my development in SolutionB because I like being able to easily reference and compile against both projects. I don't use SoluctionC at all other than as part of the following two build configurations

- BuildConfigA

  - should build SolutionA and deploy WebApplication1
- BuildConfigB

  - should build SolutionC and deploy WebApplication2 (and not
    WebApplication1 of course)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I'm pretty sure a build configuration can also build+deploy single projects, not necessarily solutions. So you could also drop sln A and sln C, and point your builds directly to the csproj files.

Ohad