# One click deployment using TFS Build 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy

Let me start with my website architecture I have 2 web servers (staff), 2 web servers (external user), 2 App Servers (wcf) and database server. I have more then 5 environments (which will have there corresponding configuration).

Using Team Build 2010 I am generating packages in the shared folder. This doesn't include database incremental script (schema changes from the last build).

Currently I taking these packages to the remote servers and deploying them using MSBUILD.

Now I need

1. One click deployment approach for this architecture. (an idea)
2. MSBUILD commands that I could use (if possible point me to the complete list)
3. How to generate incremental database script and way to update the database as part of automation (I have Database project in my solution currently I am doing a schema compare after each build)

Mostly I think BuildProcesstemplate.xaml has to be edited. Guide in this approach as well.

Things i referred (not helpful in my case)

1. PDC 09 talk by Vishal R. Joshi
2. Continuous deployment with TFS 2010 Build Agent (Hakan Forss blog)
3. Web Deployment Made Awesome: If You're Using XCopy, You're Doing It Wrong (Scott Hanselman).

Most of googling and Stack comm showed me help with simple scenario's. Please put your idea's you have or used in your projects.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why doesn't item three (Web Deployment Made Awesome) work for you?  MSDeploy is pretty robust and you can integrate it with MSBuild and TFSDeploy on CodePlex.

Comment: Can you help me, how could I integrate this with the TFS Build. Provide me a link where I could see the scenario

Answer (score 2):

You can add MSBuild arguments to TFS build to force a MsDeploy ( http://dotmac.rationalmind.net/2011/03/continuous-integration-with-tfs/ ).

However it only seems to work well (from what I can tell) in simple examples when you:

- Only have one web application ( [TFS 2010 + MSDeploy when solution has multiple web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217283/tfs-2010-msdeploy-when-solution-has-multiple-web-applications) )
- Are only deploying to one location

For more advanced deploying, I would suggest looking at an addon for TFS.

Either Tfs Deployer (OpenSource - http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/ ) where you simply customize your build to set a build quality which triggers powershell scripts to run msdeploy and can be as complex or simple as you like.

Or wait for Octopus (Commercial - http://octopusdeploy.com/ ) to become available and figure out something with that.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of MSbuild scripts and PS tools will do the job.